# how mariadb galera can help me scale writes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

if I have 1 server that's getting 30 writes per seconds and then I am moving to 3 galera nodes so now each server is getting 10 writes per seconds

but due to how galera works every server in the cluster getting every other servers writes so in the end I will have 3 server that each is getting 30 writes per seconds so I end up in the same position

what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Distributed reads. Most DBs read much more then they write. This reduces overall IO load on the nodes.
- High availability
- Distributed writes are potentially much faster on the replicated nodes, as they only need to process the actual write operation, not the enclosing database transaction (this advantage might be quite big or very small, depending on your specific workload). Due to the multi master model, processing of the actual transactions can also be distributed.

Answer (score 1):

In short: it doesn't. As you have already noted, every write has to be done on every node. If you want to scale writes you might want to look into sharding over multiple clusters or scaling your hardware up.